# Reverse search order by clicking on table header

Tags: php, html-table, reverse

I have a table that displays from MYSQL in an ordered fashion.  I am trying to get it so that if I click the header link it will reverse the order and then if I click it again it will revert to the original case.  I am getting stuck on trying to revert it.  Here is what I have so far:

```
switch($_GET['sort']){

case "asc":
$orderBy = "ORDER BY whole_date asc";
break;

case "desc":
$orderBy = "ORDER BY whole_date desc";
break;

default:
$orderBy = "ORDER BY whole_date desc";
break;
}
```

Referred to in the the SQL statement here:

```
...WHERE user_id = '$username'".$orderBy." LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage ";
```

In my table header I have the link like this in HTML:

```
<th><a href='view.php?sort=desc'>header</a></th>
```

This is where my problem is, how would I get it to revert back.  How would I include a sort=asc link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf('<a href="view.php?sort=%s">header</a>',
       empty($_GET['sort']) || $_GET['sort'] == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be reloading the page whenever you change the sort order, I guess you could use a simple ternary statement to decide what sort order to reference when writing the link:

```
<th>
<a href='view.php?sort=<? echo ($_GET["sort"] != "desc") ? "desc" : "asc"; ?>'>header</a>
</th>
```